# WinRT stretch ListBox content when ItemsPanel is horizontal StackPanel

Tags: xaml, listbox, windows-store-apps

enter image description hereI have ListBoox

```
<ListBox>
    <x:String>1</x:String>
    <x:String>2</x:String>
    <x:String>3</x:String>
    <x:String>4</x:String>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
     </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Grid Background="Green" >
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
             </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate> 
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Yellow"></StackPanel>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

I need the items of the ListBox to be stretched across the entire screen (list). It works perfectly if the StackPanel's orientation is vertical but in my case the orientation is horizontal and it doesn't work at all. Any ideas, suggestions - I need help

Comment: Can you explain the desired behaviour more clearly? How big do you want the individual items? How many do you want on the screen at once? Is the goal to fit without scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

to stretch XAML containers like StackPanels over the entire space.

Comment: Thank you Fred, if you mean this one
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate> 
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
it doesn't work, and does not takes any effects